# Set Next Previous button in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I m using **FSCalendar** in my app,i want to show **next-previous** buttons in that calendar so that user can be able to tap them as well.
Tried hard but not getting any idea.

Comment: do 1 thing add 2 `button` over `FSCalendar` `View`. and give action to that `buttons`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this code

```
@IBOutlet weak var calendar: FSCalendar!
....
@IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    calendar.setCurrentPage(getNextMonth(date: calendar.currentPage), animated: true)
}

@IBAction  func previousTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    calendar.setCurrentPage(getPreviousMonth(date: calendar.currentPage), animated: true)
}

func getNextMonth(date:Date)->Date {
    return  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to:date)!
}

func getPreviousMonth(date:Date)->Date {
    return  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to:date)!
}
```

output

[image]

Comment: It worked for month view...What changes I need to do for week view?

Answer (score 4):

You can add 2 `Button` over `FSCalendar` `View` something like that.
[image]

Here Yellow colour `View` is my `FSCalendar` and there's 2 `button` over it. Now you need to give action to that 2 `button`.

For Previous `Button` you need to call below code.

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
- (IBAction)onPreviousMonthButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.calendarVW setCurrentPage:[self.gregorian dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth value:-1 toDate:self.calendarVW.currentPage options:0] animated:YES];
}
```

For Next `Button` you need to call below code.

```
- (IBAction)onNextMonthButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.calendarVW setCurrentPage:[self.gregorian dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth value:1 toDate:self.calendarVW.currentPage options:0] animated:YES];
}
```

**SWIFT**

For Previous `Button` you need to call below code.

```
@IBAction func onPreviousMonthButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    self.calendarVW.setCurrentPage(self.gregorian.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: self.calendarVW.currentPage), animated: true)
}
```

For Next `Button` you need to call below code.

```
@IBAction func onNextMonthButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    self.calendarVW.setCurrentPage(self.dateByAddingMonths(1, currentDate: self.calendarView.currentPage), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur precious help,I have implemented the same way as u told,but is there any way to get buttons from FSCalendar itself?

Comment: @priyanshu button from `FSCalendar` means which button?

Comment: Next and Previous buttons from FSCalendar

Comment: @priyanshu, for what purpose do you want to get buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by the following code but you need to create custom buttons for Next and Previous as per your design.

```
//MARK: - Next Button Action -
@IBAction func btnNextMonthClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    let currentDate = self.calendarView.currentPage
    let date = self.dateByAddingMonths(1, currentDate: currentDate)
    self.calendarView.setCurrentPage(date, animated: true)
}

// For getting Next month 
func dateByAddingMonths(dMonths: Int, currentDate: NSDate) -> NSDate{

    let dateComponent = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponent.month = dMonths
    let newDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(dateComponent, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents)
    return newDate!
}

//MARK: - Previous Button Action -
@IBAction func btnPreviousMonthClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    let currentDate = self.calendarView.currentPage
    let date = self.dateBySubtractingMonths(1, currentDate: currentDate)
    self.calendarView.setCurrentPage(date, animated: true)
}

// For Previous Month
func dateBySubtractingMonths(dMonths: Int, currentDate: NSDate) -> NSDate{

    return self.dateByAddingMonths(-dMonths, currentDate: currentDate)
}
```